# Interpreting Incoming Data

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I've got two different analog reads from an arduino sending values over to my raspberry pi via serial connection. On my raspberry pi I'm reading the values using python. I"m wanting to store X in an address and Y in another address. How do I pull every other incoming value and store them in separate addresses. X in one and Y in another. The incoming data looks like this: X Y X Y X Y with x and y being some arbitrary values. I'm just looking for some code to grab every other incoming data. This is what im using to read data coming from my arduino.

```
import time
import serial


ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
    )


while 1:
    x = ((ser.readline().strip()).decode('utf-8'))
    #y = float(x)*100
    #z = int(y)
    #print (hex(z))
    print(x)


#This is what the incoming data looks like.
#0.01
#0.20
#0.01
#0.20
#...
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Why is this tagged with both Python 3 and Python 2? Are you using *both* versions in your project?

Comment: Well parts of my project are written on both but i guess this issue is on python 2.7 sorry. Ill remove that tag.

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far? See [mcve] for some tips about sharing code examples.

Comment: You could use [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to cycle between two containers in a list ```[[], []]```.

Comment: Okay so I updated my post with the code I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing the point here, but if you want to assign incoming values to alternating variables, then

```
while True:
    x = (ser.readline().strip()).decode('utf-8')
    y = (ser.readline().strip()).decode('utf-8')
    print(x,y)
```

Comment: When I run my program I get values every second. I want to grab the first value and then grab the second value. The data incoming is constant so I want to keep sepersting each value.

Comment: `ser.readline()` blocks until data is available, right?
And the numbers come in one to a line, right?
So the first line will read the first number into `x`, and the second line will read the next number into `y`, and so on. I think you need to explain to me why this *doesn't* separate the numbers. Understand, I don't have your hardware on hand to try this out for myself. What happens when you run the code?